How to create a custom validation attribute that works with Blazor SSR
I have a .NET 8 Blazor project where I have created some custom validation attributes. When using @rendermode InteractiveServer, they work as expected. However, when using SSR, the error messages aren't being displayed.
public class MinimumLength(int minLength) : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string _defaultErrorMessage = $"Minimum length is {minLength}";
    
    protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var errorMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage) ? _defaultErrorMessage : ErrorMessage;
        
        if (value is string stringValue && stringValue.Length >= minLength)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        
        return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
    }
}

My form is an EditForm with an OnValidSubmit="HandleSubmit". If the custom validation fails, HandleSubmit isn't called, but the error message isn't displayed in <ValidationMessage />. The error message is only written in the <ValidationSummary />. However, I would like them to be written beneath the given field.
When using a built-in validation attributes, like [Required], everything works as expected.
Can anyone tell me what I need to change to achieve this behavior?
Thanks
/Morten

I know there exists a MinLength built-in attribute, my example is a simplified version to keep track on the actual problem.

You should pass the Member Name
return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage, new[] { validationContext.MemberName});

In your own answer, you are passing DisplayName instead of the MemberName.
I believe DisplayName is meant for being used within user friendly error messages. In the base implementation of ValidationAttribute we can see that MemberName is used:
protected virtual ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) 
{
    if (!this.IsValid(value)) 
    {
        string[] memberNames = validationContext.MemberName != null ? new string[] { validationContext.MemberName } : null;
        result = new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName), memberNames);
    }
}


I have been searching for an answer for a long time. And now, after posting the question I found it.
When returning the error messages as I am doing:
return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);

The error message isn't bound to the field. To bind the error messages to the field the return should instead be:
return new ValidationResult(errorMessage, [validationContext.DisplayName]);

